# Questions without accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

What's the ratio of accepted answers / questions?

Think about it. There are so many questions without an accepted answer. It is annoying for all the people who invest time to help others.

I like the reputation/badges system so why not use this system to limit questions without accepted answer? For example:

- Reputation < 100: Users can only ask one question without accepted answer.
- Reputation < 1000: Users can ask three question without accepted answer.
- Reputation < 10000: Users can ask five question without accepted answer.

There should also be a flag to not accept any answer. But this flag should be set explicitly. For example in case all answers are wrong.

Comment: Please, please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate

Comment: There are many reasons someone might not accept an answer, just like there are many reasons someone might not vote for an answer (or question). We should not base the ability to post here on that at all, IMO. Also, please see @Oded's link!

Comment: It is ok if someone do not accept an answer. My target are questions where an author ask something and then did not care of the question and the answers any more.

Comment: It happens. You move on, you'll live. It's *fine*. I, personally, am *not* annoyed.

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to force people to accept answers that don't actually help (for example, this one)